# Newsletter for my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I have been recently looking at some websites and they have a mailing list newsletter.  If I click unsubscribe it goes straight to their server and you can unsubscribe from their server.

- What tools do they use to manage this?  I was thinking of something like Constant Contact, but with Constant Contact you have to go to their page to unsubscribe from their mailing list.
- If big websites use their own servers to send out these mailing list newsletters, wouldn't they need some 3rd party software to handle so many emails?
- What is the best way for creating something like this that's on my own website?  (aka they can go into their account and disable newsletters and it will automatically not send them emails, but it takes place ON their website)

Answer (score 3):

Please forward to [MailChimp](http://MailChimp.com)

Advantages of not sending mailings yourself:

- The probability of being Black Listed is very very low
- MailChimp handles all sending, subscribing, unsubscribing and acts accordingly to SPAM Rules
- All you need to do is be creative when doing your Email, and even that they help you out with [several email templates](http://mailchimp.com/resources/html-email-templates/) ready for all Mail clients preventing you hours of pain because there are a lot of tricks for building email templates, as it's nothing like webpages cause all the [different mail clients support features](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).
- To avoid being black listed, they throttle the sending throughout several different servers
- They will handle any "Report as SPAM"
- You are able to use opt-in or double opt-in
- You are able to change all HTML code of every page (Subscribe, Welcome, Goodbye, Unsubscribe, archive of Previous Emails, etc) so it can show just like your website

It even has a [full API](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/) that you can use to do stuff programmatically and a vast [library of resources](http://mailchimp.com/resources/) so you can learn all about Mailing

It's free if you have a list of less than 2000 subscribers and you can't send more than 12000 emails per calendar month.

Other Mailing company that I use everyday is [Campaign Monitor](http://CampaignMonitor.com), though they don't have Free Subscriptions, I love their API better :)